# Embedding subtitles to a video file in iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, subtitle

I'm relatively new to iOS development and there is something I'm trying to achieve but I'm out of luck finding good resources. I would like to embed subtitles to a video file for a project. The user records a video, after recording he inputs some sentences, and the text he input gets embedded into the video as a subtitle, one word at a time. I think this is achieved through AVFoundation but to my surprise there is relatively little information on AVFoundation except Apple's documentation (which is not of much use when you want to embed subtitles.)

How might one go about doing this? How do I need to format the text input so that it becomes a subtitle track? How do I embed that subtitle track to the video file and export it so that the video always has the subtitles on it? I hope someone here knows about these things..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt that there is standard-API to do this. But for the display-part, you could use overlay to display the text over your video. But for the embedding into the video I guess you'll have to use external libs or write something on your own.

Comment: The display part is not as problematic, I want to save the video file with the embedded subtitle. Loading subtitles as AVAssets and then exporting the resulting video might do the trick, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to create a QuickTime video with embedded subtitles (AKA soft subtitles) in it, see [avsubtitleswriterOSX](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/avsubtitleswriterOSX) sample code from WWDC 2013.

If you prefer to burn subtitles into a video, you can use `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`, as described in [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos)